# How to get dataset write progress using hdf5?

Tags: c++, hdf5, progress

When writing data to a dataset using `H5::DataSet::write`, how do I know when the writing is complete?

Is there a way to poll progress, get notified or something like that?

I am using the HDF5 C++ API on Windows.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no API for progress indication. If you want that, you have to split writing in smaller chunks and do your own progress indication. 1 MiB blocks are generally suitable. If you post the expected shape and data type of the dataset, we can give more targeted advise

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you for the response and the idea of splitting the writes and handling the progress myself. I will see if I can implement this idea once my routines are more finalized and ask a more detailed question on here if I fail.